# Select a sub-range of data from a date interval

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I have an event database. Each event has a start date and an end date. I have a plugin that can fetch data into a jquery calendar asking (json) a start date and an end date.

Let's say I have jut one "Special Event" with `start date = 01-02-2015` and `end date = 11-02-2015`.

When I call `getevent.php?start=01-02-2015&end=28-02-2015` I get all the events for the month of february ("get all the events with start date >= 01-02-2015 && end date <= 28-02-2015). The problem occur when I want to fetch data for different interval.

Let's say I want to get events for the week 2-8 Feb: when I call `getevent.php?start=02-02-2015&end=08-02-2015` I get nothing (because my "Special event" does not fit into the start date >= 02-02-2015 && end date <= 08-02-2015 query).

Do you know hot to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to obtain all events that have at least *one day in common* with queried range, right?

Assuming "variables" `eventStartDate`, `eventEndDate`, `rangeStartDate`, `rangeEndDate` you need to find rows that match the condition:

```
(eventStartDate >= rangeStartDate AND eventStartDate <= rangeEndDate)
OR
(eventEndDate >= rangeStartDate AND eventEndDate <= rangeEndDate)
```

Assuming `rangeStartDate` is always less or equal to `rangeEndDate` (and the same for event's dates) this can be simplified to:

```
eventEndDate >= rangeStartDate AND eventStartDate <= rangeEndDate
```